# Raspberry Pi "Kiosk" mode

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, kiosk-mode

Is there a way to set up a raspberry pi in a sort of "kiosk" mode where only the gui of one java program is automatically started after login?

Answer (score 4):

You need to first setup autologin for the pi user as described in the first answer.

If you are running raspbian with the default LXDE session you will need to change the file `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart`.  Doing it this way means you can still use the autologin feature.  By default this runs `lxpanel`, `pcmanfm` and `xscreensaver`, which together comprise the desktop I assume you don't want to run.

So you can put your program in that file and remove those entries, such that

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE
@xscreensaver -no-splash
```

Becomes instead

```
@/path/to/your/program/launcher_script
```

Note that this affects all user accounts, but you need to do it because otherwise the user you setup to autologin will have those programs running.

Rather than running your kiosk program directly I would run a script that runs your kiosk app, so you can deal with error handling and other setup tasks.

For example, you may also want to disable power management so that your screen doesn't turn itself off. To do this you will probably want to run the following first, to disable DPMS power management and screensaver activation and blanking:

```
xset -dpms
xset s off
xset -s noblank
```

You would then run your actual Java code in a 'while true' shell loop to restart it in case it crashes, but you might want to have some logic to detect a fast restart loop...

Comment: In order to be able to use xset, the following must be installed:
$ sudo apt-get install x11-xserver-utils

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways how you could start an application, such as that java program, rather than a desktop environment.

One of the possibilities would be to follow the steps under *Run a Script at Login* on this website:
http://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/raspberry-pi/5/raspberry-pi-auto-start.html

You may want to take a look at *Auto Login* as well.

Comment: Nice. I can automatically start the programm with the script. But how can I disable the desktop environment?